# Epson XP-760 colour printer only prints in black with Ubuntu 17.04 (it worked fine on Debian 8)

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

- My system is Ubnuntu 17.04 + latest updates.
- My printer is an Epson XP-760 colour printer.

When the Operating system is loaded, it automatically picks up my XP-760 printer. This has been loaded via CUPS.

Looking in **System Settings, then Printers** I can see that the system has already found my printer XP-760 Series.

When I click on **Printer Icon**. I see that the option **orientation requested** has a value **0** and cannot be edited.

The Option  **Print Quanity**. This has a value **0** and cannot be edited.

I can now see the first screen of the printer dialog, and am able to make a test print.

The information on the test print, from the printer is as follows:

Driver ippeve.ppd ver 2.2
 Description  Epson XP-760 Series
 Print location  EPSON26B5A8.local   (port631)
 Printer Make and Model  Epson Xp-760 series, driverless, cups-filters.
THis is were it is wrong - The Driver should be epson-inkjet-printer-escpr.
The printer only prints in black, even if a picture is printed.

I have also used Debian 8, and this loads the correct driver.
 `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr` and prints in colour.

Do you have any personnel on the Ubuntu side of the fence, to look into these problems, or is it only the Linux Community that is using this site.
If it is only the Community, I am waste my time.
Bill

Comment: The question is unclear. There is a driver that supports your printer. Please describe how did you install it.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to introduce some meaningful punctuation and paragraphs? It's very hard to read that wall of text. I tried to separate it a little as best as I can.

Comment: Obviously OP did not install the proprietary driver.

Comment: You need to install the driver from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver from [Epson drivers site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

Enter your printer model and press Search.

Accept the license and download a deb file according to your architecture (amd64 or i386). Copy this file to your Home folder and run in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i epson*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Then go to System Settings -> Printers and install a new printer there.

Comment: I followed your steps but to me the answer is not complete -> my system automatically still used the default driver.  Go into the printer properties, change "Make and Model" and choose the proprietary driver!!!